Changes are not pick up in vs 2019
I use  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.41
I run my project in start without debugging mode and then I make a small changes in view for example I add  Hello world  and then when I refresh the page in the browser the changes are not applied to the view, I mean I cannot see the above hello world header. There is not any error and also the changes are not visible when I inspect the page.
I Clear the cache but it did not work.
when I click start without debugging again the changes are applied to the view.
Hope you help me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
